# Understanding output of `lspci -nm`

Tags: pci-express

I'm trying to understand the columns in an `lspci` line output:

```
<pci_device_id> <?> <??> <???> <????> <?????> <??????>
```

Example output:

```
$ lspci -nm | grep d7:17.0                                  
d7:17.0 "0880" "8086" "2018" -r07 "8086" "0000"
```

Additional documentation:

```
-m
Dump PCI device data in a backward-compatible machine readable form. See below for details.

-n
Show PCI vendor and device codes as numbers instead of looking them up in the PCI ID list.
```

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/lspci.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lspci -nnn` provides a slightly more labeled view along with documentation [here](https://diego.assencio.com/?index=649b7a71b35fc7ad41e03b6d0e825f07)

```
$ lscpi | grep d7:17.0
d7:17.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake-E M2PCI Registers [8086:2018] (rev 07)
```

```
<pci_device_id> <class_code> <vendor_id> <product_id> -r<revision_number> <??> <???>
```